# script not load if partial view call by jquery ajax

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

in .Net MVC 3 i try to run a script..The script is in a partial view. if i call partial with Html.RenderAction it works but if i call partial view in page by jquery ajax its not work.

Partial View

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<script src='http://ad.reklamport.com/rpgetad.ashx?tt=t_iddaa_habersayfalari_mac_detay_300x250&ciid=&rnd=" + Math.random() % 99999999 + "'></" + "script>");            
</script>
```

View

It works..

```
<html>
    <head>        

    </head>
    <body>        
        @{Html.RenderAction("Partial");}

    </body>


</html>
```

it not works...

```
<body>        
        @{Html.RenderAction("Partial");}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Home/Partial",
                dataType: "html",                
                success: function (result) {                    
                    $("#content").html(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
        </script>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </body>
```

i need to use second way.. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

this is because the `<div id="content">` has not loaded to the dom. try placing the JS script after the content div

```
<body>        
        @{Html.RenderAction("Partial");}

        <div id="content">

        </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Home/Partial",
                dataType: "html",                
                success: function (result) {                    
                    $("#content").html(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

or you can wrapp your ajax request document ready event handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(function{
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Home/Partial",
                    dataType: "html",                
                    success: function (result) {                    
                        $("#content").html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                    }
                });
            });
 </script>
```

Comment: if i write in script only alert("hello world") it works.. i think script is not load ?

Comment: could it be that you have forgotten to add a reference to jquery?